# Unable to send Multipart-Form data with AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js

Currently, I've trying to write a method in Objective C that takes in a UIImage and a NSString and makes a POST request to a server. Unfortunately, I have trouble getting it to send anything. When I tried the form with an HTML form, I was able to successfully upload a photo and the parameters. However, I am unable to replicate it in my iOS app. I keep getting a 404 error when I try to make a POST request.

I've tried two different methods of sending a multiform data POST request according to its Github page to no success. I've debugged the UIImage in Xcode and I see that it actually exists. I'm thinking it has something to do with the parameters I'm sending. Should the parameters be part of formDataAppend or just as a dictionary as I did below?

The commented part corresponds with the tutorial on its Github. The uncommented section contains parts from browsing Stackoverflow still to no avail.

```
+(void) uploadPhotoWithID:(NSString *)ownerID andPhotoImage:(UIImage *)image andCompletionHandler:(void (^)(MZPhoto *, NSError *))callback{

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"owner_id": ownerID};

//    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:upload_photo_url parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
//        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"photo" fileName:@"temp.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
//    } error:nil];
//    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
//    
//    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask  = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
//        if(error){
//            NSLog(@"File Upload Failed");
//            
//        }
//        else{
//            NSLog(@" %@", responseObject);
//            MZPhoto *photo = [[MZPhoto alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject error:nil];
//            callback(photo, nil);
//        }
//    }];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:upload_photo_url]];
    [manager POST:upload_photo_url parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"photo" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } progress:nil
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
              NSLog(@" %@", responseObject);
          } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
              NSLog(@" Failed");
          }];



}
```

Here is my Node.JS function,

```
exports.upload_photo = function(req, res, next) {
    var owner_id = req.body.owner_id;
    console.log(owner_id);
    pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            done();
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).json({success: false, data: err});
        }

        var query = client.query("INSERT INTO photos (likes, dislikes, user_id) " +
                                    "VALUES (0, 0, $1) RETURNING photo_id, likes, dislikes, user_id", [owner_id]);
        var result;
        console.log(req.file);

        query.on('row', function(row) {
            row.file_url =  baseFileURL + row.photo_id + '.jpg';
            result = row;
        });

        query.on('end', function() {
            done();
            fs.rename('./static/photos/' + req.file.filename, './static/photos/' + result.photo_id + '.jpg', function(err) {
                if(err) console.log("Error Renaming the file!");
                return res.json(result);
            });
        });
    });
    console.log("Received photo upload from: " + owner_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following `function`

```
- (void) postServerRequest:(NSDictionary *)paramDict withData:(NSData*)fileData andType:(uploadType)uploadType Callback:(ResponseBlock) block{

    NSString * strServiceURL = @"Your Webservice URL";


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    [manager POST:strServiceURL parameters:paramDict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        if (fileData!=nil){
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:fileData name:@"Key name on which you will upload file" fileName:@"Image name" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
        }

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        DLOG(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
        block(responseObject,nil);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        DLOG(@"Error: %@", error);
        block (nil , error);
    }];
}
```